# Using react-icons without icon name tag

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-icons

I'm using [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons).

In documentation normal usage like this:

```
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
<FaBeer />
```

But I can't use by this way because icon names comes from props. I need to use like this:

```
<Icon name={props.icon} />
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Implement a wrapper

Comment: How? Any example? @DennisVash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a wrapper, for example:

```
import { FaBeer, FaAdobe, ICON_NAME } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ICONS = {
  [ICON_NAME.FaBeer]: <FaBeer/>,
  [ICON_NAME.FaAdobe]: <FaAdobe/>
}

const Icon = ({name}) => <>{ICONS[name]}</>
```